# Unable to Snap Evince PDF Viewer to the Right or Left of the Screen After Opening a PDF

Tags: pdf, evince

I am having trouble with the Evince PDF viewer. Once I open a PDF, I'm unable to snap it to the right or left of the screen, despite several attempts using different methods (such as the super key + right/arrow or manually dragging it). Interestingly, I am still able to minimize the window or make it full screen.

I've noticed that this issue only occurs after opening a PDF; when I first launch the app, I'm able to snap the window into place without any issues.

I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app, but the problem persists.

Comment: How do you open the PDF?